# How to use Postfix to send email in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, postfix-mta

I want to send a verification email and I want to do it by using Postfix.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#introduction AFAIK `sendmail` uses postfix

Answer (score 3):

Postfix provides a `sendmail` command for compatibility with the original `sendmail` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail).

Once postfix is installed, you can follow the regular Laravel instructions for `sendmail`.

See `config/mail.php`, you'll have to change the driver to `sendmail`. Some visitors might still use older versions of Laravel (like 4.2), in this case, the file is `app/config/mail.php`.

To test the configuration, you can use a one-liner like this in `php artisan tinker`, but you'll have to create a view in `resources/views/test.blade.php` (With any content you want).

```
// Change username for your real username
Mail::send('test', array('key' => 'value'), function($message){$message->to('username@localhost','me')->from('noreply@localhost')->subject('test');});
```

The email should appear in this file: `/var/mail/$USER`